# Hebrew vowel positioning

Tags: luatex, accents, hebrew

Is there a way in LuaLaTeX (second best would be XeTeX) to finetune the positioning of Hebrew vowel signs? For some fonts if both vowels and cantillation marks are present, they might overlap, which should be avoided. I would need something similar as `\skew` in plain LaTeX.

Comment: I think this is something that the font should take care of, rather than TeX.

Comment: @brian-ammon Indeed, but sometimes it doesn't and I need to kludge

Comment: as always, a test document would help (and also in this case spell out which are the vowels and where you want them moved to...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you *can* do this. But first make sure:

1. You can't use a better font
2. You have correctly set up your font

Consider this example which only uses the SBL BibLit font, but with different open type settings. The correct output is only obtained when `fontspec` is passed `Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate`.

If you leave out `Contextuals=Alternate`, the furtive patah is wrong. If you leave out `Script=Hebrew`, everything is completely messed up.

But frankly, I would use a better font rather than manually moving things.

**Note:** I'd be surprised if the manually constructed word copies and pastes correctly.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\sblgood{SBL BibLit}[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate]
\newfontfamily\sblhalfbaked{SBL BibLit}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\sblbad{SBL BibLit}
\begin{document}
\textdir TRT \pardir TRT

\sblgood
וְר֣וּחַ

\sblhalfbaked
וְר֣וּחַ

וְר֣וּח\kern -4.75pt  ַ

\sblbad
וְר֣וּחַ

ו\kern -2pt  ְ\kern 2pt
ר\kern -3.5pt  ֣\kern 3.5pt
ו\kern -2pt\lower 4pt\hbox{ ֺ}\kern -0.5pt
ח\kern -4.75pt  ַ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Sometimes you need it if you use [rafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafe) or similar stuff even with SBL Hebrew font.

Comment: @Kazibácsi, do you have an example word that renders wrong with SBL Hebrew (and reference from BHS)? `xetex` uses a better font shaping library than `luatex`, so that might be an issue. Or could actually be a bug in either font or shaping library that should be fixed. As far as I know, SBL Hebrew is meant to reliably be able to produce everything in the BHS.

Comment: How can I know that I should add `Contextuals=Alternate`? And why isn't it default?

Comment: @Zvika, Perhaps you could ask a new question (with a good MWE for people to test). I can't remember exactly how I discovered I needed to use `Contextuals=Alternate`. Perhaps just by trial and error and looking at what OpenType features the font supports. `xetex` renders וְר֣וּחַ correctly without `Contextuals=Alternate`. But I'm not sure if this is because `xetex` turns this feature on by default or because it's font rendering of complex scripts is superior to `luatex`.