# Combining a diactritics with dotted circle in Hebrew text

Tags: luatex, fontspec, polyglossia, hebrew

I want to demonstrate various diacritics in Hebrew.

Unicode contains a Dotted Circle `U+25CC` symbol for that purpose. However, when I try to combine them in `\texthebrew` the characters do not combine (unlike the same diacritics with Hebrew letters).

[image: misaligned]

Curiously, they do combine when used outside of `\texthebrew`:

[image: aligned]

But then I would not be able to use a font without support for Hebrew as the main font.

How do I achieve the same combining behaviour in Hebrew text?

Live demo: https://www.overleaf.com/read/pnzryjjgdgjs

Full reproducible example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cardo}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Cardo}

\title{hebrew combining circ}

\begin{document}
Here the diacritics render correctly: \texthebrew{בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים}

Here they are misaligned: \texthebrew{ְ◌}

It works outside of \textbackslash{}texthebrew: ְ◌

But then I cannot use a different font (Gentium).

\end{document}
```

I am using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Looks like I can just use `\hebrewfont{ְ◌}` to achieve the desired rendering ‍♀️

Comment: Misread `\texthebrew{}` as *tex the brew*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Unicode, the combining characters always have to *follow* the letter they should combine with. So if you want the codepoints U+25CC (DOTTED CIRCLE) and U+05B0 (HEBREW POINT SHEVA) to combine, you have to *first* write U+25CC, *then* U+05B0.

Your example on the other hand orders them differently: It has the combining character first, then the dotted circle afterwards. Therefore they don't combine.

If you correct the order, you get

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Hebrew]{Cardo}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Hebrew, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Cardo}

\title{hebrew combining circ}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
Here the diacritics render correctly: \texthebrew{בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים}

Here they are misaligned: \texthebrew{◌ְ}

It works outside of \textbackslash{}texthebrew: ◌ְ

But then I cannot use a different font (Gentium).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now you might wonder why it no longer works outside of `\texthebrew`: Since HEBREW POINT SHEVA is only used in Hebrew, the font contains positioning rules for it only for the Hebrew script. Therefore the placement outside of `\texthebrew` (where the script is set to Latin) is basically random.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried it in that order first but I forgot to pass `Script=Hebrew` to `\newfontfamily` in my real code [after learning about it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443026/hebrew-vowel-positioning) ‍♀️